Problem with labels when there are multiple tex files
I have a TeX document that combines multiple subfiles, each with uniquely named labels. However, I'm encountering an issue with the \ref command. For instance, an equation labeled aaa in the first subfile and another labeled bbb in the second subfile should reference different equations. But if both equations are named the same, such as (1.1), \ref{bbb} incorrectly points to the equation labeled aaa in the first subfile. When I hover the mouse over bbb, it points to /project/numbershere#equation.1.1. I suspect this is the cause of the problem. I want labels to be referenced in their own subfiles. Do you know why this happens and how I can fix it?
I have simplified the project and shared it here. The contents include:
sections/AAA.tex
sections/BBB.tex
example.sty
main.tex

Note: I prefer not to change the file settings, as modifications often cause issues in the complete project.
sections/AAA.tex:
%\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}


%\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\c@thm
\makeatother
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

%--------Meta Data: Fill in your info------
\title{Title 1}

\author{Author 1}

% \scalebox{1}{\includegraphics[]{logo.png}}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

%\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}\label{aaa}
    a = a
\end{equation}

equation \ref{aaa}

sections/BBB.tex:
%\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}


%\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\c@thm
\makeatother
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

%--------Meta Data: Fill in your info------
\title{Title 2}

\author{Author 2}

% \scalebox{1}{\includegraphics[]{logo.png}}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

%\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}\label{bbb}
    b = b
\end{equation}

equation \ref{bbb}

example.sty:
\ProvidesPackage{example}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multirow}

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\usepackage{float}

%Header styles
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

%makes available the commands \proof, \qedsymbol and \theoremstyle
\usepackage{amsthm}

%Ruler
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

%Lemma definition and lemma counter
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

%Definition counter
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]



%Example cenvironment
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{examle}{Example}

%Example counter
\newcommand{\reiniciar}{\setcounter{example}{0}}




\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{quest}[thm]{Question}
\newtheorem{claim}[thm]{Claim}
\newtheorem{ppty}[thm]{Property}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{defns}[thm]{Definitions}
\newtheorem{con}[thm]{Construction}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{exmps}[thm]{Examples}
\newtheorem{notn}[thm]{Notation}
\newtheorem{notns}[thm]{Notations}
\newtheorem{addm}[thm]{Addendum}
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{limit}[thm]{Limitation}


\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{rems}[thm]{Remarks}
\newtheorem{warn}[thm]{Warning}
\newtheorem{sch}[thm]{Scholium}




\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{scale=1,angle=0,opacity=0.5,contents={}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}


%\usepackage{authblk}




\usepackage{leftindex}

main.tex:
\documentclass[twoside]{article}


\usepackage[
 paperwidth=170mm,
 paperheight=245mm,
 left= 25mm,
 top=35mm,
 right=40mm,
 bottom=35mm,
 headsep=12.5mm,
 headheight=14.5pt, %%% 3mm is too small
 heightrounded
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{example}

\usepackage{tableof}

\usepackage{titling}
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \oldmaketitle
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thetitle}%
}
\makeatletter
\let\l@chapter\l@section
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\z@}{\m@ne}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeindex


\begin{document}

\clearpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{sections/AAA}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\clearpage

\include{sections/BBB}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\clearpage

\end{document}


I've not tested, because no computer available. But: How should a reader distinguish equation 1.1 and equation 1.1? How should a reader distinguish section 1 and section 1? I would hardly recommend to remove the \setcounter{section}{0} commands from main.tex. IMHO the \l@chapter code also does not make sense, because article does not provide chapters.

The document is a collection of articles, each with its own title page and abstract.

You should shorten your example more. E.g. pgfplots, textcomp or multirow are hardly relevant.

I'm not sure which of these settings are relevant, so I've left them unchanged, as they might be related to the problem.

well you could do something against your uncertainty by testing it: Remove the package or the code and look if the problem persists (in some testing environment naturally, not in your real document). The worst that can happen is that you get an error. This will improve your skills in making minimal example and you will get then much faster an answer for your future problems.

BTW: Using subfiles seems to be irrelevant for the problem.

hyperref uses the section and equation number to create anchors. And if you reset the section manually to zero you get duplicate names and pdftex will ignore the second anchor. There is then a warning in the log:
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{section.1}) h
as been already used, duplicate ignored

You must make the anchor name unique, for example by using an additional counter:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{abssection}
\counterwithin{section}{abssection}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\section{AAA}

\begin{equation}\label{aaa}
    a = a
\end{equation}

equation \ref{aaa}


\clearpage
\stepcounter{abssection} %resets the section counter

\section{BBB}

\begin{equation}\label{bbb}
    a = a
\end{equation}

equation \ref{bbb}

\end{document}


Thank you, that solves the problem. However, I didn't use the \section{AAA} and \section{BBB} commands. It still works, but could there be an issue?

sorry but your example was unusable so I simply ignored that and used my crystal ball to write an answer. If it doesn't work somewhere you will have to make a new (and better) question. Check the log for pdftex warnings about destinations.
